# How the attribute pattern works in the Oracle Cloud Data Integrator?

Tags: design-patterns, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-data-integrator

I have configured an extraction in Oracle Data Integrator from OCI, and the table that I want to extract, is already configured in the database to save the extraction. The problem is that the name of the attributes are not the same and I want to link the names by using a pattern.

[View from the pattern linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z59EF.png)

As you can see in the image, for example in the source I have tables like ApInvoicesAcctsPayCombinationsId, this should link with the attribute ACCTS_PAY_COMBINATIONS_ID, or for example ApInvoicesAmountPaid should link with AMOUNT_PAID.

I haven't find information of how to use patterns from Oracle, I would like to see some examples.

I want to convert with Oracle pattern ApInvoicesAcctsPayCombinationsId into PAY_COMBINATIONS_ID, removing  always the "ApInvoices" from the string and converting camel to underscored.

Thank you.